# Apart from the lack of native Outlook support, why should one prefer S/MIME over PGP/MIME for email?

Tags: tls, email, pgp, smime

From my (still quite subjective) point of view, GnuPG/PGP is superior to SSL (or more specifically, PGP/MIME over S/MIME; maybe in other areas SSL is the better choice), e.g. due to the support of subkeys to [separate signing and encryption certificates](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8559/digital-certificate-deployment-using-two-certs-for-each-user/8563#8563) and the Web of Trust instead of having to [blindly trust a CA](http://blogs.comodo.com/it-security/data-security/the-recent-ra-compromise/) - including the ability to revoke certificates without a CRL or OCSP.

But in contrast to S/MIME, PGP (MIME or not) requires some additional user effort, and seamless integration (such as Enigmail in Thunderbird) in Outlook ≥ 2010 (unfortunately widely used in the business world) requires a plugin (the only usable one I found is the [Outlook privacy plugin](https://code.google.com/p/outlook-privacy-plugin/), which does currently only support plain-text PGP).

But apart from this usability issue, is there a sensible reason to prefer S/MIME over PGP/MIME?

Comment: They have different trust models - you are comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: @symcbean I'm not entirely convinced of that - basically SSL has a restricted hierarchical Web of Trust where only a single signature can be put on a certificate (the signing certificate can be signed as well of course) and one basically trusts on client programmers to implement sensible CA trusts. This could be done with PGP as well, if you set a CA's trust to ultimate and implicitly trust everything they sign. I consider SSL an alternative to a  subset of PGP, or does SSL actually offer anything PGP could not offer? (Yes, TLS doesn't usually use PGP, but that's not because it couldn't...)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The main reason to prefer one technology over the other *is* usability. Regardless of the tools you use, email security will depend mostly on how well the users cooperate -- most of the confidentiality of their emails rests on their ability not to do anything stupid with their data, and to react appropriately in unusual conditions. You will get decent security only if the tools they use are available, easy to use and reliable. Therefore, it is difficult to compare S/MIME and OpenPGP *in abstracto*.

However, we can still make some distinctions on the [PKI model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_infrastructure). S/MIME relies on [X.509](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509), a behemoth of a standard which is meant to support a **hierarchical PKI** with controlled trust delegation from a limited set of *trust anchors* and down short paths. OpenPGP uses a [Web of Trust](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_of_trust) which is decentralized. Your expression "blindly trust a CA" says a lot on your own preferences, but is quite subjective.

If you look at how X.509 and OpenPGP operate, you will see that in the Web of Trust, everybody is a CA; hence, while in X.509 you put your trust into a handful of CA, in the Web of Trust you put your trust in... everybody ? That's because most people forget half of the WoT system. In a true WoT, the graph of certification (i.e. who signs the key of who) should be overconnected.

When you want to validate the public key of someone (let's call him Bob), then you need to find *certification paths* which lead from you to Bob; such a path begins by your public key (which you know "absolutely") and each step is a signature computed over the public key of the next individual in the path. Security in the WoT model comes from the verification of *many* paths which all begin by you and end on Bob, but with no other individual being common to any two paths. When everybody can act as a CA, any single path is "potentially suspect": when people sign other people's keys late at night and under the auspices of heavy alcohol drinking, you cannot expect all paths to be 100% reliable. An attacker intent on forging a fake key for Bob will just have to find a few gullible or intoxicated individuals. The WoT credo is that "the crowd is right": an attacker may subvert some people, but not most of them. Thus, if you can find many valid paths which lead to Bob, then Bob's key is probably genuine, because bribing or deceiving that many people would have been "probably too hard".

Bottom-line is that the Web of Trust is **hard**. The description above uses the fuzzy terms "few", "many", "most" and "probably". We do not know how to estimate the number of paths which must be built in order to achieve a given level of security; in fact, we do not know how to quantify a "security level". It is unclear whether WoT can work at all. OpenPGP implementations tend to use a "reliability percentage" which is a totally unsubstantiated guesswork. Of course, in practice, nobody spends time to rebuild many chains; you are already lucky if you find *one* chain.

**When I must exchange confidential data with customers**, I use OpenPGP -- but not the Web of Trust. I use OpenPGP because the usual implementations have the ability to *bind* keys to indentity permanently: if I can make sure *once* that the key is genuine, then my software will remember it and things will be safe thereafter. So the customer and I exchange the key fingerprints when we meet in person, or over a phone call (which we assume to be safe from impersonations -- eavesdropping is not an issue here).

Such binding is not supported by S/MIME implementations. They *could* do it (although certificate expiry makes it slightly more difficult) but they do not. It is not intrinsic to X.509 (the X.509 model makes it *possible* to change your certificate every five minutes, but it does not make it *mandatory*); but deployed implementations work that way. Usability trumps the PKI model, as I said above, so that's OpenPGP for me.

(**Note:** in another context, [HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure) relies on the X.509 hierarchical PKI with a few dozens of hardcoded trust anchors, and the same issues arise there too; e.g., see [Convergence](http://convergence.io/), which is a proposal to, indeed, bind keys to servers in a semi-permanent way, and which relies on the same "crowd is right" mantra as the WoT. And yet they do that with X.509 certificates, which shows that the actual *format* for certificates is not that important.)

Comment: "blindly trust" is quite subjective indeed - what I more or less mean is that if one of the small number of root CAs is compromised (again...) basically everyone is fooled due to the hierarchy, while it is (hopefully) unlikely that those PGP keys _I_ chose to trust as "real" CAs are compromised unless an attack is specifically aimed at me. Of course this does assume both my Web of Trust and yours truly are diligent about assessing the Web of Trust... Side note: One attempt to use the PGP Web of Trust for https is the [monkeypshere project](http://web.monkeysphere.info/why/#index1h2)

Comment: Update: in 2019 GnuPG mostly fell to a 'sibyl' attack -- in WoT any person can be a certifier, thus also can any fake identity -- or large numbers of fake identities, creating signed-key blobs so large GnuPG fails. Since there is no way to determine which (if any) added signers are real, the only solution found so far is to discard all non-self-signatures, eliminating WoT. @TobiasKienzler: and as of Oct 2021, monkeysphere is gone: https://web.archive.org/web/20211002033629/http://web.monkeysphere.info/

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Thomas Pornin, the main reason to prefer S/MIME over PGP encrypted email is usability. Usability is crucial, because low usability is the main reason for users not to use encryption. I want to elaborate on *why* the usability of S/MIME is (currently) better than that of PGP.

The biggest difference between S/MIME and PGP is the fact that S/MIME enjoys built-in support by virtually every email client on every platform. PGP, on the other hand, almost always requires additional software to be installed.

Therefore, it is much easier to make your communication partners use S/MIME, as they need not install additional software, but they just need to learn how to set up the existing support in the software they already use and know.

In some circumstances, it is impossible to use PGP, because

- users are not allowed to install software on their computer (very often in companies)
- PGP support does not integrate well or not at all with their email client (like on iOS devices, for example) which renders it unusable for everyday use

With regard to the different trust models of S/MIME and PGP, on one hand, S/MIME need not be restricted by the hierarchical model:

Using self-signed CAs, it is not necessary to trust any of the big CAs. Of course, your communication partner must (manually) trust your self-signed CA, but this needs to be done only once, and from a viewpoint of security, isn't it more secure to trust a certificate issued by someone you know rather than some CA that is defined as trustworthy by someone else?

On the other hand, the web of trust in PGP has its well-known problems, like faked PGP keys, practically non-revocable keys, and keys that are not verified. There are attempts to overcome these problems (like the verifying keyserver at keys.openpgp.org) though. The web of trust model is quite complex, and many users do not really understand it or at least not fully.

However, there is one aspect of PGP that has a better usability, and that is the distribution of keys. Using keyservers, a user can automatically obtain another person's key and immediately use it for encryption, while with S/MIME, certificates can usually be obtained only from directories within a company (usually LDAPs). Yet, exchanging S/MIME certificates using signed emails is not too complicated or demanding for most users.

Eventually, the choice between S/MIME and PGP depends on the scenario. We use both, but most of the times, I found S/MIME more convenient and easier to use than PGP.